# How to translate following nodejs code into ES6

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

This is my first javascript project (also a first programming project after a decade) so go easy on me.

I am working on VueJS and using a module form nodejs. Now, I have a need to add some functionality to the nodejs module. I copied relevant files into my project. However, the files have syntax different from my code (it uses `'use strict;` and `require` vs my code that uses export/import.

The code in question looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var SSH = module.exports;
var Enc = require('./encoding.js');

SSH.parse = function (opts) {
  var pub = opts.pub || opts;
  var ssh = SSH.parseBlock(pub);
  ssh = SSH.parseElements(ssh);
  //delete ssh.bytes;
  return SSH.parsePublicKey(ssh);
};

/*global Promise*/
SSH.fingerprint = function (opts) {
  var ssh;
  if (opts.bytes) {
    ssh = opts;
  } else {
    ssh = SSH.parseBlock(opts.pub);
  }
  // for browser compat
  return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
    return 'SHA256:' + require('crypto').createHash('sha256')
      .update(ssh.bytes).digest('base64').replace(/=+$/g, '');
  });
};
...
...
```

How can I translate this code into ES6 style. Where I can import this and make a call like `SSH.fingerprint(publickey)`.

Comment: fingerprint is an antipattern. It enforces a promise with synchronous operations, this requires callers to be asynchronous to consume SSH.fingerprint(publickey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node modules use Commonjs Modules syntax.

In Node, we use `require` to import which is equivalent to `import` in es6. For export, we use `modules.exports` or `exports` which is equivalent to the `export` keyword in es6 Modules

import in NodeMoules

```js
    var Enc = require('./encoding.js');
```

es6 Modules

```
    import * as Enc from './encoding.js';
```

export in NodeMoules

```
    const variable = 3;
    module.exports = {
    variable
    };
```

or

```js
    exports.variable = 3;
```

es6 Modules

```
    export const variable = 3;
```

---

Edit to answer OP's comment

> how do I translate var SSH = module.exports;

In Node Modules, whatever you defined on `module.exports` object it will be exported by the module. This means if you define anything on its reference it will also be exported because it is js reference it will point to the same object.

```
var SSH = module.exports;
```

this code, save a reference of module.exports in SSH variable. if you defined any key on the SSH variable it will be exported i.e SSH.fingerprint.

So in order to export fingerprint in es6 Module you just need to do this

```
export const fingerprint = function (opts) {
  var ssh;
  if (opts.bytes) {
    ssh = opts;
  } else {
    ssh = SSH.parseBlock(opts.pub);
  }
  // for browser compat
  return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
    return 'SHA256:' + require('crypto').createHash('sha256')
      .update(ssh.bytes).digest('base64').replace(/=+$/g, '');
  });
};
```

FYI, `exports` keyword in node modules is also a reference to `module.exports`

---

Update for the second comment, Your final code will become:

```
'use strict';

import * as Enc './encoding.js';

export const parse = function (opts) {
  const pub = opts.pub || opts;
  const ssh = parseBlock(pub);
  ssh = parseElements(ssh);
  //delete ssh.bytes;
  return parsePublicKey(ssh);
};

/*global Promise*/
export const fingerprint = function (opts) {
  let ssh;
  if (opts.bytes) {
    ssh = opts;
  } else {
    ssh = parseBlock(opts.pub);
  }
  // for browser compat
  return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
    return 'SHA256:' + require('crypto').createHash('sha256')
      .update(ssh.bytes).digest('base64').replace(/=+$/g, '');
  });
};
...
```

Comment: Much clearer. Thank you so much. I have a pretty good understanding now. The only issue remains is the line ```ssh = SSH.parseBlock(opts.pub);```. Shall I just change that to ```ssh = parseBlock(opts.pub);``` It is a function defined locally in the same file.

Comment: if it is defined in the same file you can do it

Comment: Thanks again. Highly appreciate you taking time to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
exports.funcName = async (params) => {
  // your code
}
```

on other working file

```
const fileName = require('../path')
//call it
fileName.funcName()
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the right direction. However, how do I translate ```var SSH = module.exports;```?

Comment: @tinkertwain I have updated my answer to address this.